# Apache InternalHttpClient: Determining local port number

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to debug http client request. I need to get the local port number that was used when the connection was made. I can use the HttpClientContext to get the connection, and retrieve the local port when the connection is successful. However, in cases where the IOExceptions are thrown, I get a ConnectionShutdownException when retrieving the local port number. Any clue on how I can obtain the local port number for all http requests in case of error.

Comment: A `ConnectionShutdownException` means that the connection doesn't currently exist either because it was never established or because of some problem that caused the connection to close. If there is no connection, there is no open port and by definition no port number.

Answer (score 2):

This is for HTTPClient 4.0.1 (last version I have with me).
I did not find any simple one liner...

The part of http client that actually binds sockets to local host/port and connects to the remote host/port is, unsurprisingly, the SocketFactory. In HTTPClient, the socket factory is associated to a SchemeRegistry, that in turns belongs to the connection manager. Note that the HTTPClient's SocketFactory is NOT a javax.net.SocketFactory, but a wrapper around such an object. You define a scheme like so :

```
SchemeRegistry schRgstr = new SchemeRegistry();
Scheme httpScheme = new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80);
schRgstr.register(httpScheme);
```

Of course, org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory is an Interface, so you can decorate it to do anything you want in particular, this will come in handy.

The part of httpclient that calls the socket factory is called the `ClientConnectionOperator` (which is an interface too). This object is actually also tied to the connection manager, and not the client *per se*. So if you want to customize the connection operator, you may override the connection manager too, for example, like so (anonymous class) :

```
ThreadSafeClientConnManager connMngr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams, schRgstr) {
  protected ClientConnectionOperator createConnectionOperator(SchemeRegistry schreg) {
    return new YourConnectionOperator(schreg);
  };
};
```

The lifecycle model of the socket goes like so:

1. When the connection manager needs a now connection, it calls `createConnection` on the operator (which basically does nothing but create an internal object that eventually will hold the actual socket).
2. Further along the way it calls `openConnection`
3. openConnection goes to the `SocketFactory` and asks for a new Socket, then tries to connect it like so (here, sf is the "httpclient socket factory")

   ```
   sock = sf.connectSocket(sock, target.getHostName(),
         schm.resolvePort(target.getPort()),
         local, 0, params);
   ```
4. If this call fails, an exception is thrown and more information will not be accessible. We'll get back to that.
5. If the connectSocket works, though, the `prepareSocket` method is called on the connection operator. And so, you can override the method and put the port information into the context, (or anything else you fancy) :

   ```
   @Override
   protected void prepareSocket(Socket sock, HttpContext context, HttpParams params) throws IOException {
     super.prepareSocket(sock, context, params);
     context.setAttribute("LOCAL PORT INTERCEPTOR", sock.getLocalPort());
   }
   ```

The HttpContext instance that is used is passed when you invoke HTTPClient, so you can access it even if the call fails later, because of some other exception. When you place your call, make it so:

```
HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(targetUrl.getUrl());
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get, ctx);
```

In this code, if the client could go as far as step 5, you have your port info accessible, even if an exception occurs later on (connection drop out, timeout, invalid HTTP, ...).

**Going further**

There is still a dark zone in all this : if the call fails at step 4 (actual opening of the socket, like if you have a DNS error while resolving the destination host name)... I'm not sure this case is actually interesting to you, (I can not see why it would be). Seeing dealing with it starts to get "messy", you should really consider wether or not you need this.

For that we need to start overriding really deep, and that involves lots of work - some of it I would not consider very good design.

The complexity arises because authors of HTTPClient did not provide the necessary methods one could override to get to the information you need. Inside the socket factory, the interesting point is :

```
sock = createSocket();
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
sock.bind(isa);
// go on and connect to the server
// like socket.connect...
```

There is no method to override that splits the local and the server side of the socket openning, so that if any socket exception is thrown on the server side, your access to the socket instance is lost, and the local port info gone with it.

But all is not lost because we do have one entry point we can play with : the createSocket method! Default implementation is

```
public Socket createSocket() {
    return new Socket();
}
```

But as Socket is not a final class, you can... play with it !

```
public Socket createSocket() {
    return new Socket() {
      @Override
      public void bind(SocketAddress bindpoint) throws IOException {
         super.bind(bindpoint);
         // get the local port and give the info back to whomever you like
      }
    };
}
```

Problem is : this works with plain sockets (because we can create an anonymous subclass), but this does not work with HTTPS, because you can not simply instanciate a Socket on this case, you have to do :

```
return (SSLSocket) this.javaxNetSSLSocketFactory.createSocket();
```

And you can not create an anonymous subclass in that case. And as Socket is no interface either, you can not even proxy it to decorate it. So you *could* (uglyest code ever) create a Socket subclass that wraps and delegates to the SSLSocket, but that'd be desperate.

**So, recap time.**

If we only care about sockets that were at some point connected to the server, the solution is fairly simple.

A scheme registry we builb is used in a custom `ConnectionManager` that overrides the `ConnectionOperator`. The operator's overriden methods is `prepareSocket`that allows us to simply update the `HttpContext` of any request we send with the port information. Which is an easy way to find the information when everything goes well.

If we want to care about local ports attributed to a socket that never, ever, got connected (which I would argue is of limited use), one need to go deeper.

Our own `SchemeRegistry` should be designed to have custom `SocketFactories`. These should probably be decorators or the default ones... the `createSocket` overriden method allows us to "intercept" the binding on the local port (and store this into maybe a `ConcurrentMap<Socket, Integer>` or a `ThreadLocal`), and by overriding 'connectSocket' we trap any exception that may happen, and rethrow it, but not before wrapping it in our own exception type that can hold local port information.  That way, if the exceptions passes though when you call the client, by checking the cause chain, you will find your port data. If no exception occurs, we clean or map instance / thread local.

Comment: No, most of times above I mean HTTPClient's SocketFactory interface. For HTTP, default implementations simply create their own sockets directly (new Socket()), but for HTTPS, org.apache...SocketFactory actually wraps a javax.net.(SSL)SocketFactory.